# Is it possible to filter stats in SP 2010 by individul pages?

Tags: 2010, statistics

We use SharePoint 2010 and the site has about 51,000 items. It also gets about 65,000 views per week.

Every Monday I have to run reports on site usage, such as Top Pages etc. As you can imagine, with 65,000 views over 51,000 items it can be a real pain providing specific stats about specific pages.

My questions:

- Is there a way for me to filter the results to narrow down the stats, as opposed to having to navigate multiple pages to find the stats I need?
- If so, do I need 3rd party software to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with SharePoint’s native functionality.

If you’re running weekly reports, I assume you’re already familiar with accessing the ribbon in the Site Web Analytics Reports pages. Follow these steps:

1. Run your weekly Top Pages report as you normally do
2. Within the ribbon, click on the Filter option
3. A window appears with a *Page URL Contains* field
4. Now enter a part of the URL that you know the page you need stats on has:

   - For example, let’s assume you need to provide stats on various policies you have on the site, such as Leave_Policy.aspx, Travel_Policy.pdf, IT_Policy.docx etc
   - You can then enter the word *policy* in the *Page URL Contains* field
5. Click OK
6. The Top Pages report will now filter by all content that contains the word *policy* in the URL. This works regardless of whether it’s a Wiki page, a MS Word document, a PDF, etc as long as the characters *policy* appear in the URL.

Now you can easily grab the stats for individual pages as you need.